# Center aligned inline svg misaligns with 1 pixel height change but perfectly aligns with 2 pixel height change in a Flex container on Safari browser

Tags: svg, safari, vertical-alignment

The container contains 2 inline svgs wrapped in `stop-icon` (dummy) tag elements. One expects both the inline svgs to be center aligned even though their sizes vary by 1 px in each dimension but only one of them is aligned, the other one is slightly off center, ON SAFARI.

**Question**: Is there a way to ensure the alignment never goes slightly off on
Safari regardless of the inline svg size ?

```css
.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 36px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.timer-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #313131;
  min-width: 8ch;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
  
.cancel-icon {
  
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5px;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.cancel-icon svg {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
}

.cancel-icon.inline2 svg {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="timer-text">
    <div>00:00:23</div>
  </div>
  <stop-icon class="cancel-icon inline1">
    <svg width="27" height="27" viewBox="0 0 27 27" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M13.5 24.75C11.9062 24.75 10.425 24.4641 9.05625 23.8922C7.6875 23.3203 6.49687 22.5281 5.48438 21.5156C4.47187 20.5031 3.67969 19.3125 3.10781 17.9437C2.53594 16.575 2.25 15.0938 2.25 13.5C2.25 11.925 2.53594 10.4531 3.10781 9.08437C3.67969 7.71562 4.47187 6.525 5.48438 5.5125C6.49687 4.5 7.6875 3.70313 9.05625 3.12188C10.425 2.54063 11.9062 2.25 13.5 2.25C15.075 2.25 16.5469 2.54063 17.9156 3.12188C19.2844 3.70313 20.475 4.5 21.4875 5.5125C22.5 6.525 23.2969 7.71562 23.8781 9.08437C24.4594 10.4531 24.75 11.925 24.75 13.5C24.75 15.0938 24.4594 16.575 23.8781 17.9437C23.2969 19.3125 22.5 20.5031 21.4875 21.5156C20.475 22.5281 19.2844 23.3203 17.9156 23.8922C16.5469 24.4641 15.075 24.75 13.5 24.75ZM13.5 23.0625C16.2188 23.0625 18.4922 22.1484 20.3203 20.3203C22.1484 18.4922 23.0625 16.2188 23.0625 13.5C23.0625 10.7812 22.1484 8.50781 20.3203 6.67969C18.4922 4.85156 16.2188 3.9375 13.5 3.9375C10.7812 3.9375 8.50781 4.85156 6.67969 6.67969C4.85156 8.50781 3.9375 10.7812 3.9375 13.5C3.9375 16.2188 4.85156 18.4922 6.67969 20.3203C8.50781 22.1484 10.7812 23.0625 13.5 23.0625ZM10.125 17.7188H16.875C17.1187 17.7188 17.3203 17.6391 17.4797 17.4797C17.6391 17.3203 17.7188 17.1187 17.7188 16.875V10.125C17.7188 9.88125 17.6391 9.67969 17.4797 9.52031C17.3203 9.36094 17.1187 9.28125 16.875 9.28125H10.125C9.88125 9.28125 9.67969 9.36094 9.52031 9.52031C9.36094 9.67969 9.28125 9.88125 9.28125 10.125V16.875C9.28125 17.1187 9.36094 17.3203 9.52031 17.4797C9.67969 17.6391 9.88125 17.7188 10.125 17.7188Z" fill="#313131"/>
    </svg>
  </stop-icon>
  <stop-icon class="cancel-icon inline2">
    <svg width="27" height="27" viewBox="0 0 27 27" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M13.5 24.75C11.9062 24.75 10.425 24.4641 9.05625 23.8922C7.6875 23.3203 6.49687 22.5281 5.48438 21.5156C4.47187 20.5031 3.67969 19.3125 3.10781 17.9437C2.53594 16.575 2.25 15.0938 2.25 13.5C2.25 11.925 2.53594 10.4531 3.10781 9.08437C3.67969 7.71562 4.47187 6.525 5.48438 5.5125C6.49687 4.5 7.6875 3.70313 9.05625 3.12188C10.425 2.54063 11.9062 2.25 13.5 2.25C15.075 2.25 16.5469 2.54063 17.9156 3.12188C19.2844 3.70313 20.475 4.5 21.4875 5.5125C22.5 6.525 23.2969 7.71562 23.8781 9.08437C24.4594 10.4531 24.75 11.925 24.75 13.5C24.75 15.0938 24.4594 16.575 23.8781 17.9437C23.2969 19.3125 22.5 20.5031 21.4875 21.5156C20.475 22.5281 19.2844 23.3203 17.9156 23.8922C16.5469 24.4641 15.075 24.75 13.5 24.75ZM13.5 23.0625C16.2188 23.0625 18.4922 22.1484 20.3203 20.3203C22.1484 18.4922 23.0625 16.2188 23.0625 13.5C23.0625 10.7812 22.1484 8.50781 20.3203 6.67969C18.4922 4.85156 16.2188 3.9375 13.5 3.9375C10.7812 3.9375 8.50781 4.85156 6.67969 6.67969C4.85156 8.50781 3.9375 10.7812 3.9375 13.5C3.9375 16.2188 4.85156 18.4922 6.67969 20.3203C8.50781 22.1484 10.7812 23.0625 13.5 23.0625ZM10.125 17.7188H16.875C17.1187 17.7188 17.3203 17.6391 17.4797 17.4797C17.6391 17.3203 17.7188 17.1187 17.7188 16.875V10.125C17.7188 9.88125 17.6391 9.67969 17.4797 9.52031C17.3203 9.36094 17.1187 9.28125 16.875 9.28125H10.125C9.88125 9.28125 9.67969 9.36094 9.52031 9.52031C9.36094 9.67969 9.28125 9.88125 9.28125 10.125V16.875C9.28125 17.1187 9.36094 17.3203 9.52031 17.4797C9.67969 17.6391 9.88125 17.7188 10.125 17.7188Z" fill="#313131"/>
    </svg>
  </stop-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is as specified. The distance between the middle and the sides differs by 0.5px, but the smallest unit in positioning is 1px. Browsers are at liberty to account for the needed rounding as they see fit. Your design must not depend on one specific behavior.

Comment: @ccprog if i include the svg as an image <img> this issue does not happen. Then it realigns on every single pixel change in height.
Is there a way to make sure the center alignment never goes slightly off on safari regardless of the `inline svg` size ?

Comment: You can try to set `shape-rendering: geometricPrecision` in CSS for the `<svg>` element. But as before, browsers are at liberty to do something about it or not, and diffferent browsers may do different things. Accept it, everything less than 1px is out of your control.